# Is the polynomial $\frac{1}{64}x^6 + 3x^4 - \frac{1}{4}x^3 - x + 6$ irreducible over $\Bbb Q$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

How do I approach proving irreducibility/reducibility in a polynomial with rational coefficients? Can I apply Eisenstein in some way?

Is the polynomial $\frac{1}{64}x^6 + 3x^4 - \frac{1}{4}x^3 - x + 6$ irreducible over $\Bbb Q$?

Comment: It is enough to consider $x^6 + 192x^4 - 16x^3 - 64x + 384$ but probably not easier.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate the help. But where would I go from here with such a large polynomial? Would I have to show it is irreducible over some finite field?

Comment: Try mod $5$....

Comment: Do you already know that this polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ if and only if it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$? If yes, you can try finite fields.

Comment: How can I find out if it is irreducible over $\Bbb Z $? I've been trying finite fields but I am struggling. Would you mind explaining?

Comment: Polynomial $Ax^n +Bx^{n-1} + Cx^{n-2} +. . .a.b.c.d...$ is reducible if a or b or c ... or all of them divide x. In your question $384=3 ˟  2^7$, you can see that the algebraic sum of terms is not zero if you plug in 2 and 3 for x and conclude that the polynomial is not reducible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace $x$ by $2y$ gives
$$\frac{1}{64}x^6 + 3x^4 - \frac{1}{4}x^3 - x + 6 = y^6+48y^4-2y^3-2y+6$$
Now apply Eisenstein criterion with $p=2$.